# How to handle service application failures developed by Hive JDBC?

Tags: jdbc, hive, bigdata, huawei-mobile-services

I'm developing a service application based on the Hive jdbc-examples project, fail to run the application. 
[image: hive]

I normally use Huawei's big data products to perform Hive's jdbc sample development, which always fails to run the application.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, try either one of the following methods:

Method 1

Put the core-site.xml configuration file to classpath according to the Hive jdbc-examples sample project.

Method 2

In the code, explicitly load the core-site.xml file:

......conf = new Configuration();
String userdir = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "conf" + File.separator;
conf.addResource(new Path(userdir + "core-site.xml"));......

Method 3

In the code, set hadoop.security.authentication to kerberos:

......CONF = new Configuration();
CONF.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos");......

See [more](https://forum.huawei.com/enterprise/en/failure-of-running-the-service-application-developed-based-on-the-hive-jdbc-sample-code/thread/544325-899).